# Tab Controls effecting other Controls

Tags: vb.net

Hopefully I've explained myself good enough this time. Can't seem to get a real answer. Trying to make it so when I select certain tabs, certain controls on the left will disappear or reappear.

http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/7533/scrnshotg.jpg

Also, when "Stats" is selected, I need it to auto-select "Frequency"

Ex. On click/focus/select (whatever, nothing seems to work)...
ComboBox.Visible = True

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Managing tabs and their effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806900/managing-tabs-and-their-effects)

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `TabControl.TabIndexChanged` event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindexchanged%28v=VS.100%29.aspx